# Jquery autocomplete not updating the result in the UI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a HTML structure like:

```
   <label for="supervisors">Assign the Supervisor: </label>
   <input class="supervisors"/>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
                  <script type="text/javascript">

                    jQuery(function() {

           jQuery( ".supervisors" ).autocomplete({
               source: "/users/autocomplete_for_supervisors",
               minLength: 2,
               select: function( event, ui ) {
                     log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
 "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );


          }
        });
       });
              </script>
```

and in my controller I have added the action for autocomplete_for_supervisors which is working when I gave in the URL as:

http://localhost:3000/users/autocomplete_for_supervisors?term=ar

But when I type something in the input box in my firebug the jquery is excuted and calling the respective function and returning the response in the firebug. But I am not getting the response below in the input box.

How do I get my returned result below in my input text box?

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are usingthe wrong variable names in the function / file that actually retrieves your data.

This is very similar to my problem which got solved: [Having problems with jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809863/having-problems-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete)