# Having problems with jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the new [autocomplete function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) in jQuery UI, but I'm having some problems.

I'm able to retrieve data from the DB (I can see it in FireBug), but I'm not able to display the dropdown list (or alert the data).

This is my jQuery code:

```
  jQuery('#brand_search').autocomplete({
            source: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.search.php?instance=brand",
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 50,
            select: function(e, ui) {
              alert(ui);
            }
        });
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
/* ------------------ Brand Autosuggest ------------------------- */
  function autosuggestBrand($dal)
  { 
    $result = $dal->getRowBySearch('sl_label','name', $this->term);   
    $brands = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
      {
          array_push($brands, array(
            "id"      => $row['id'], 
            "name"    => html_entity_decode($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') )
        );
      }     
    }
    echo json_encode($brands);          
  }
```

I've see these two guides:
http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget

But still can't quite figure out how to display / alert the fetched data.

This is the result from `echo json_encode`

```
[
  {"id":"4642","name":"Mo Koshji"},
  {"id":"4627","name":"MO-A"},
  {"id":"4626","name":"MO'CYCLE"},
  {"id":"4628","name":"mo851"},
  {"id":"4629","name":"Mob Action"}
]
```

Comment: @Steven: Do you see any results when you type in the input with the autocomplete widget attached to it?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - No, nothing on the interface. But I do see, through Firebug, that the PHP is returning JSON result.

Comment: In your `select` function, if you add `console.log(ui)` instead of `alert`, what do you get in the console?

Comment: @Ken Redler - I get nothing. The only output in the console is from the `GET` action.

Comment: maybe it worth nothing but have you tried to alert ui.item.id or ui.item.name? because the default property names are label and value

Comment: Try generating your result in this format: `[ { "id": "the_id", "label": "the_label", "value": "the_value" } ]`

Comment: Why are you adding the autocomplete inside the .click event handler and not just adding it to the element?

Comment: @Ken Redler - ISn't my output already in that format using `echo json_encode`? Se updated question.

Comment: @Steven: Try changing `name` in your PHP to `value`.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker and @Dalen - Ah, that worked. Now I get the drop down. Thanks!

Comment: PS. You have to leave an answer so I can mark this thread as solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct your php array with the following in order to get a correct json output for jquery-autocomplete:

```
array_push
(
   $brands,
   array
   (
      "label"  => $row['id'], 
      "value"  => html_entity_decode($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') )
    );
);
```

because jquery autocomplete needs those json property names to run the autocomplete as specified on the documentation:

> The local data can be a simple Array
>   of Strings, or it contains Objects for
>   each item in the array, with either a
>   label or value property or both. The
>   label property is displayed in the
>   suggestion menu.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Would have been easier if you just said to use `value` instead of `name` ;)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this (take it out of the click event handler):

```
jQuery(function()
{  
 jQuery('#brand_search').autocomplete({
        source: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.search.php?instance=brand",
             minLength: 2,
             delay: 50,
             select: function(e, ui) {
               alert(ui);
              }         
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Having it inside `click` was from old code using autocomplete plugin. Moving it ouside click does not change anything - I tried.