# Jquery autocomplete not returning anything!

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have the code below that has stopped working all of a sudden. The auto complete doesn't bring up any results.

I made a temp form to manually send the data, it return json data fine. Then I tested the ajax was actually making a request by saving the json to a text file when the page is called, that worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Customer Management System</title>
<link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/stack_ci_2/public_html/includes/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/stack_ci_2/public_html/includes/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/stack_ci_2/public_html/includes/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

// Get matches for customer search.
    $("#customer_search_ref").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('customer/ajax_customer_search'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#customer_search_ref").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        // Inputs customer data into forms.
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#customer_name").focus();
            $("#tabs").tabs("select",0);
        }
    });

});
```

JSON data returned on manual post and in text file.

```
[{"id":"114","name":"Claire","surname":"Taylor","address_1":"add1","address_2":"add2","address_3":"add3","city":"city","county":"county","postcode":"postcode","country":"country","email":"email","home_tel":"home","mobile_tel":"mobile","work_tel":"work","notes":"notes","value":"Claire Taylor - 114","label":"114 - Claire Taylor"}]
```

I thought it might be the label and value not being returned but it is.

Also the js and css files are being loaded successfully and XHR requests all these have been tested in firebug.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

check out this:
[Having problems with jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809863/having-problems-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete/)

you have to use `label` and `value` as main property names of your json object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use firebug console to look at the response content.

Comment: I dont see how this would help as the output looks the same as my HTML exepct for the url is generated for the ajax just it works. What am i looking for?

Comment: @John - in the firebug console tab, click the little downward arrow, make sure the `Show XMLHttpRequests` is ticked. Reload the page. You should see a line in the console, a url of the AJAX request. Click the + arrow on the line to see what was returned - is it correct what has been returned?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your returned JSON is not as per the format which source needed. I think it is suppose to be ['value1','value2',.....] and not [{key:value1,key2:value2}].

Please refer the jquery UI autocomplete source options once more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.map method to merge your data to create a right response

```
success: function(data){
    var result = $.map(data, function(item){
        return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.id
        }
    });
    response(result);
}
```