# jquery autocomplete with json not working

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have successfully used the autocomplete function with a hard coded array. But, when I try to use data from a php file, it doesn't work.

My jquery is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#game_two_other").autocomplete({
        source: "mlb_other_teams.php",
        minLength: 3
    });
});
</script>
```

My php code is as follows.

```
$mister =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM al_other WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($other = mysql_fetch_assoc($mister)) 
{

    $team_one   =   $other['team_one'];
    $team_two   =   $other['team_two'];

}

$json = array($team_one, $team_two);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Any ideas or thoughts?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: did u try to debug `$json` try `echo $json` and see in `firebug`

Comment: Can you please also post the output of your PHP script?

Comment: Also: You should go back to your old questions and select an answer for them by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer that helped most. Otherwise people might no longer help you.

Comment: It echoes out as follows: ["Texas Rangers","Tampa Bay Rays"]

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that it was such a big deal... but, i'll do that from now on.

Comment: How exactly did you notice, that it doesn't work? Are there no results showing up? Have you tried Firebug to look at the return value from the AJAX request?

Comment: no results are showing up... i haven't tried firebug though..

Answer (score 1):

When you produce json for jquery's autocomplete it has to containtains `label` and/or `value` properties:

```
$mister =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM al_other WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());

$json = array()

while ($other = mysql_fetch_assoc($mister)) 
{

   $json[] = array('label'=>$other['team_one']);
   $json[] = array('label'=>$other['team_two']);

}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Similar question: [Having problems with jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809863/having-problems-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete/)

Comment: Looks like you should add the 'value' => ... as well, but hopefully @Lance figured that out.

Comment: actually it is not required to provide both label and value, documentation states that if one is missing the other will be used for both purposes